# Run virtuoso ISQL commands in .Net application for importing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, virtuoso, dotnetrdf

I'd like to import (or automate the import function in Virtuoso) some RDF files on a .Net application to my local Virtuoso by using some commands in ISQL workspace.

The commands in PowerShell are:

```
>ISQL 
    >ld_dir_all('PATH', '*.rdf', 'ONTOLOGY'); 
    >set isolation='uncommitted'; 
    >rdf_loader_run();
```

It means that, the isql command must finished and then I have to run the next.

I've tried to use PowerShellInstance in .net but when I combine all commands in this form : `PowerShellInstance.AddScript("ISQL;ld_dir_all('PATH', '*.rdf', 'ONTOLOGY');set isolation='uncommitted';rdf_loader_run();");` there is an error.

So I need your help or ideas for automation import data to Virtuoso in .Net application. (Maybe there will a solution in dotNetRDF!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combined command is telling PowerShell to execute 4 commands on the OS commandline.  Instead, you need to tell PowerShell to run iSQL, which must then be told to execute 3 statements.

Note that none of these statements is iSQL-specific; you're just executing them *through* iSQL.  You can actually execute these statements through any data connection to Virtuoso, including ADO.NET (or ODBC, JDBC, etc.).  I do not have specific advice for doing so with `dotNetRDF`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll search on others ways for data connection. @TallTed is there any other way (not isql) for importing rdf files to Virtuoso in .net (with or without dotNetRDF) ?

Comment: @alirezartbd, your RDF files must already be in one of the `DirsAllowed` on the Virtuoso server host, so you should be able to execute the same 3 SQL statements via [the ADO.NET Provider for Virtuoso](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/VirtuosoWikiWeb/VirtAdoNet35Provider). For more help, try the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) or (for Commercial) an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).  Also see, [Loading RDF into Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert).